# Trying to understand this toggleClass() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function in question:

```
function toggleElementClass(element, className) {
if (element.className.indexOf(className) > -1) {
    element.className = element.className.replace(new RegExp(className, 'g'), '');
} else {
    element.className += " " + className;
}}
```

I'm trying to identify issues with this code. I've had experience with jQuery and JavaScript here and there, but I cannot seem to come to a solid conclusion with what I've seen so far. I've seen a lot of examples using the current .toggleClass() function from jQuery but none that help me analyze the code above.

One problem I think I can identify is that it never seems to remove a class. Only adds more but I've had problems attempting to test this on plunker. Any help would be appreciated. What problems can you identify with this method?

Want to make an edit: This questions is purely for my own understanding. I'm not intending to use this or re-write a tool that already exists in jQuery! Thanks for all who have submitted answers so far!

Edit: For anyone who may be interested. This isn't a perfect solution (adds spaces between classes the more you toggle). It seems to get around the false positive the original code would cause!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="football">Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <script>
      function toggleElementClass(element, className) {
        var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + className + '\\b', 'g');
        if (regex.test(element.className)) {
        element.className = element.className.replace(regex, '');
      } else {
        element.className += " " + className;
      };
    };

    $("h1").click(function() {
      toggleElementClass(this, "test")
    })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're referencing jQuery, why re-write `toggleClass()` in the first place? Additionally, your plunkr works fine - the issue is that you can't include a function with parameters in a `click()` - By including `()`, you're executing your function, not passing it. You need to wrap that it in an anonymous function: `function() { functionHere(p1, p2); }`

Comment: Even if does remove, it's dangerous, i.e: `toggleElementClass(e, 'col')`, makes the element `<div class=" col col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-6">` be `<div class=" -md-4 -sm-2 -xs-2 -lg-6">` because of the `RegExp()`.

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery (which I applaud), you can use [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). You can use it out of the box if you don't care much about IE9-, or use a polyfill in case you need to support a specific old browser.

Comment: This question is purely for my own understanding. Not intended as a re-write. Thanks for your input!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is fine for most circumstances, although will get false positives when searching for `foo` and a `football` class is available.

The specific issue with your code is with how you are attaching the `click` event to the `h1`. Currently you're setting the *result* of the function call to the event handler, not the function *reference*. This means the function is called immediately on load and the scope is not what you're expecting (it's the `window` instead of the `h1`) hence the 'undefined' error you receive.

To fix this you need to wrap the click event handler in an anonymous function:

```js
function toggleElementClass(element, className) {
  if (element.className.indexOf(className) > -1) {
    element.className = element.className.replace(new RegExp(className, 'g'), '');
  } else {
    element.className += " " + className;
  };
};

$("h1").click(function() {
  toggleElementClass(this, "a")
})
```

```css
.a {
  color: #c00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="a">Hello Plunker!</h1>
```

***That being said*** the function is completely redundant, as you can use either jQuery's `toggleClass()`:

```js
$("h1").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('a')
})
```

```css
.a {
  color: #c00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="a">Hello Plunker!</h1>
```

Or alternatively you can use `classList.toggle()`:

```js
document.querySelector('h1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('a');
});
```

```css
.a {
  color: #c00;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="a">Hello Plunker!</h1>
```

Comment: The *logic* may be fine, but the implementation isn't. `toggleClass("foo")` will happily "toggle" the `foo` in the class `football`.

Comment: Ah yes, true. I'll update it with a note about that.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on the false positive aspect? Very interesting. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Imagine you have `<a class="football">` and you search for the class `foo`. You will match on the `foo` of `football`, hence the output will be `<a class="ball">`. For that reason I strongly suggest you do not use your function, but one of the two lower methods. The jQuery one would seem most appropriate as you're already using jQuery anyway

Comment: Thank you Rory! This was purely for my understanding. Not intending to use the funcion. Just trying to analyze what problems it has and I was having trouble discerning that. Mostly because I was unfamiliar with RegEx.

Comment: Will do, how would you suggest avoiding that false positive case? Other than just using a prebuilt option. Thanks in advance!

Comment: By using either of the bottom two methods. There is no point using the function you had in the OP as the functionality is already provided in a more robust way

Comment: I completely understand, but this is purely for my own education. I don't plan on using this. I'm just interested in a solution to that problem. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Ah, ok. In which case I'd amend the regex to look for either a word boundary after the match, or the end of the string: `.replace(new RegExp(className + '(?=[\s"'])', 'g'), '')`

Comment: I am getting a missing ) after argument list when trying to make that change.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to escape the `'`: `.replace(new RegExp(className + '(?=[\s"\'])', 'g'), '')`

Comment: Interesting.. I'm getting this very vague error now.. : Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

I really appreciate you quick resonses!

Updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/xr3TDToyiEE95IL2BGm1?p=preview

Comment: The error is occurring when I add: + '(?=[\s"\'])' to the Expression. The toggle works without it. All be it with that false positive we've discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some problems:

- You'll get false positives for a partial class name match (searching for `foo`, will match `foobar`). If you fix this problem, be careful how you do it, since you must allow for more than one kind of space separator.
- The replacement will leave extra spaces, which isn't huge, but can add up.
- You're using a regular expression with the assumption that the class name will not contain any special regex characters. You already are getting the index, so why not use that? You'll need a loop to make sure they all get removed, but it's going to be safer.

Comment: Thanks spanky,
so would you say using the index instead of regex would be a much safer way of replacing an element?

Comment: @KyleD.Fiala: I would say so, also likely faster than creating a regex on the fly. Will take a little more work to set up and get right, but for a library function like this, I think it makes sense.